# How can I query the youtube api to return the yt$videoid?

Tags: json, api, youtube

I'm currently using this to query for the first video matching deadmau5:

https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=deadmau5&v=2&alt=json&max-results=1&prettyprint=true

This returns a bunch of info including the video id, and seems wasteful on both my end and there's. All I need is the youtube id, is there a more efficient way to return only the video id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it makes use of jquery so you may need to include jquery library before running it

```
        $(function(){
        var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=deadmau5&v=2&alt=json&max-results=1&prettyprint=true';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
            var videoLength = $(data.feed.entry).length;
            for(x=0; x<videoLength;x++)
            {
                var videoUrl = data.feed.entry[x].media$group.yt$videoid.$t;
                console.log(videoUrl);
            }
        }
        });
    });
```

Check out console to see the video id. It can also work with a playlist and will provide all the video ids under a playlist

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This is more or less what I was looking for because I'm parsing this within rails:

[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=deadmau5&v=2&alt=json&max-results=1&prettyprint=true&fields=entry(media:group(yt:videoid))](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=deadmau5&v=2&alt=json&max-results=1&prettyprint=true&fields=entry%28media%3agroup%28yt%3avideoid%29%29)

Note the difference is I added fields=entry(media:group(yt:videoid))

The above answer is great though and probably better in a bunch of situations

Comment: yeah i thought of doing with jquery because it has no server dependencies and can work with the help of browser only... anyways show your rails skills and make it work there